# pandoc-crossref does not resolve proper equation referencing from LaTeX to Word

Tags: pandoc, latex-to-word

When i send a LaTeX document through Pandoc to create a MSWord file, the equation referencing is lost. I am using `pandoc-crossref` for referencing. Does anyone has an idea how resolve this issue?

The conversion commandline reads as:

```
pandoc index.tex --filter pandoc-crossref -M autoEqnLabels -M tableEqns -o index.docx
```

The LaTeX example file is `index.tex`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Some reference to an AMS style equation \ref{eq:one} 
\begin{align}
    f(x) &= x + a \label{eq:one}
\end{align}
and a reference to a standard \LaTeX \ one \ref{eq:two}.
\begin{equation}
    z(x) = x^2 \label{eq:two}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The MSWord output `index.docx` shows this,

[image]

where the reference labels are listed as `[eq:one]` and `[eq:two]` but instead i would expect a (1) and (2) here.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `pandoc` + `pandoc-crossref`, you might want to try `make4ht` instead.